# Oracle index maximum key length exceeded

Tags: oracle, indexing, oracle11g

I get error **ORA-01450: maximum key length (6398) exceeded** as I try creating below index

```
CREATE INDEX FORENAME_SURNAME ON CARD_HOLDER( REGEXP_REPLACE (UPPER( FORENAME ),'\\s|-|_|\\.|\\:|\\,',''), REGEXP_REPLACE (UPPER( SURNAME ),'\\s|-|_|\\.|\\:|\\,','') );
```

Error code is fair clear but my columns are 100Bytes each so how is possible index exceed the max??

And db_block_size  = 8192 not 6398.

Below columns definition

```
  CREATE TABLE CARD_HOLDER
(   "CARD_HOLDER_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"TITLE" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
"FORENAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
"SURNAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this with concatenation instead of two different columns. However this is only a workaround and might not be useful unless you are using the query as such with concatenation.

```
CREATE INDEX forename_surname ON
    card_holder ( regexp_replace(upper(forename),'\\s|-|_|\\.|\\:|\\,','')
    || regexp_replace(upper(surname),'\\s|-|_|\\.|\\:|\\,','') );
```

Answer (score 0):

The length of **6398** is the maximal length of the index key in a 8KB block size tablespace as the block must contain the key *plus some overhead*.

Why are you getting the error for your 100 byte columns can be easily demonstrated.

Let's define a view with your additional columns

```
create view ch2 as
select c.*, REGEXP_REPLACE (UPPER( FORENAME ),'\\s|-|_|\\.|\\:|\\,','') for2,
REGEXP_REPLACE (UPPER( SURNAME ),'\\s|-|_|\\.|\\:|\\,','') sur2 
from CARD_HOLDER c
```

If you check the data types of the new columns you see

```
select COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, DATA_LENGTH
from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'CH2' and column_name in ('FOR2','SUR2');

COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, DATA_LENGTH
FOR2         VARCHAR2   4000
SUR2         VARCHAR2   4000
```

Oracle expects the result of the `regexp_replace` could have the maximal length of 4000, which end in total of 8000.

So what to do?

[Ask Tom](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/how-to-fix-ora-01450-maximum-key-length-6398-exceeded-errors) has a nice overview of workarounding the problem with key length.

Among others solution you could define a tablespace with a larger block size for your index.

You may also step back and use `TRANSLATE` (or `REPLACE`) to remove the unwanted characters such as

```
TRANSLATE(upper(FORENAME),'x'||CHR(9)||CHR(10)||CHR(11)||CHR(12)||CHR(13)||' -_.:,','x')
```

Here Oracle asumes the result will be *only* 400 charater long so there will be no problem with the index key.